# need a simple example for the synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

```
public class Test implements Runnable{
    private String name;

    public Test(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void run() {
        blah(name); 
    }

    public synchronized void blah(String obj) {
        System.out.println("Here: "+obj);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test x = new Test("X");
    Test y = new Test("Y");

    Thread tx = new Thread(x);
    Thread ty = new Thread(y);

    tx.start();
    ty.start();

}
```

This example should help me to understand synchronization, but I don't. This is because if I remove the word `synchronize`, it printed the same output (random)

Comment: [Have a look here for a better example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_synchronization.htm)

Comment: "This example should help me to understand synchronization, but I don't." can we know where did you get that example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is technically correct, but there is no timing dependent conflict in your synchronized block.  As such, there is no chance that you will see different output, regardless of the ordering of the calls.

In addition, you create two resources, and there is no cross-thread communication between the two resources, so effectively you've tested two synchronized blocks once each.

You need an example that can break when not synchronized.

Here is an example that can break

```
public class Counter {

    int count;

    public Counter() {
       count = 0;
    }


    public int getCount() {
       return count;
    }

    public /* need synchronized here */ void update(int value) {
       int buffer = 0;
       buffer = buffer + count;
       buffer = buffer + value;
       count = buffer;
    }

}

public class UpdateCounter extends Thread {

    public UpdateCounter(Counter counter, int amount) {
        this.counter = counter;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void run() {
       System.out.printf("Adding %d to count\n", amount); 
       counter.update(amount);
       System.out.printf("Count is %d\n", counter.getCount());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Counter counter = new Counter();

    UpdateCounter x = new UpdateCounter(counter, 30);
    UpdateCounter y = new UpdateCounter(counter, 100);

    x.start();
    y.start();

}
```

With an example like this, one would eventually see a series of lines that indicated some value was being added to the counter, but the counter would update by the wrong value.

This is because one thread will eventually get paused with a buffer holding the "next" value, and the other thread will race across the same block of code, storing its "next" value into count.  Then the paused thread will un-pause, and store its "next" value effectively removing the amount added by the thread that raced ahead of it.

By adding the synchronized keyword, only one thread is allowed entry into the update block, and the race condition I described above cannot occur.

Note that this is an example that can fail with bad synchronization, and not a good way to implement a counter.

Answer (score 2):

Synchronization is irrelevant here because your two threads are each synchronizing on their own Runnable. There is no shared lock, and no shared data.

If you pass the same Runnable instance into each Thread then they will share the same lock. If your Runnable does something in a thread-unsafe way (like using ++ to increment a shared variable (an instance variable of the Runnable), or adding the entry to a shared ArrayList) then you can create a situation where removing synchronization can make the code break (with the understanding that breakage may not happen reliably, that's what makes multithreaded programming fun).

Making toy examples like this is not a good preparation for real-life multithreading. Threads shouldn't be in the business of implementing locking, they should be accessing data objects that enforce their own invariants.